# Junit5 Contorller Test with SpringbootTest can’t load method getParameterName()

Tags: junit5, spring-boot-test

version:spring-boot-starter-test 2.2.12.RELEASE
When I run junit5 test,I want test controller。
there is code

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = RuoYiApplication.class,webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public abstract class BaseTest {

    @SpyBean
    TokenService mockTokenService;

    @Autowired
    public MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    public TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
```

```
public class CommonControllerTest extends BaseTest {
    @SpyBean
    CommonController commonController;
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testFileDownloadNotExists() throws URISyntaxException {
        
        String fileName = "...";
        URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromUriString("/common/download")
            .queryParam("fileName", fileName)
            .build()
            .encode()
            .toUri();
        
        RequestEntity<Void> downloadRequest = RequestEntity
            .get(uri).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
        
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(downloadRequest.getUrl(), String.class);
        assertThat(response.getBody()).isEqualTo(null);
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

When the request send to controller,It can't get method ParameterNames,it alos run inspectClass function read class information,but without ParameterNames and The program enter the breakpoint inspectClass read nothing becase of wrong path(com/**/CommonController$MockitoMock$1821216982.class).

It normal when I run SpringBoot Application,it can  enter the breakpoint inspectClass read class inputstream。

How solve this problem?

[image: test]

[image: read class info]

[image: read class]
[image: the right read class info]
[image: read class path error]

when I change the mockito version from 3.1.0 to 3.6.28 this com/**/CommonController$MockitoMock$1821216982.class changed to
com.ruoyi.web.controller.common.CommonController
[image: succss by change mockito version]

[image: the old version class name]

[image: the new version class name]

Comment: Can you please share your test class setup? What Spring Boot test annotations are you using, etc.

Comment: Yes,I think it a version bug。

Comment: Please add the **entire** test class. We can't see what annotations you are using on top of your test class. Also why do you use `@SpyBean` of the controller you want to test? When writing tests for a Spring MVC controller you usually use `@WebMvcTest(YourContorller.class)` and let Spring Boot create a minimal test context for you that includes the real controller bean. You then use `@MockBean` (or `@SpyBean` if there's a strong reason) for the collaborators of your class.

Comment: Yes,I have added and improved the description

Comment: Generally speaking, for unit testing, SpyBean should not be used to mark the Controller to be tested

Comment: I also try @WebMvcTest,but it have many bean need to mock.I haven't found the right way

Comment: If it is an integration test, the Mock controller situation must be considered separately.

Comment: You're mixing quite a lot of concepts in your test. You start the embedded servlet container and configure `MockMvc`- it's normally either-or. If you want to write an integration test and invoke your endpoints over HTTP using the `TestRestTemplate`, remove any `MockMvc` configuration and the `@SpyBean` config for the controller. For an isolated controller test, go with `@WebMvcTest`. Also this [Spring Boot unit vs. integration testing overview](https://rieckpil.de/spring-boot-unit-and-integration-testing-overview/) might help you.

Comment: OK,thanks.I will read it.